# How to change the X-Windows default border width for all window frames in Ubuntu using Gnome 2.28

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, x-windows, appearance

Way back from Windows 3.x days to the latest 64bit Windows 7 (classic/standard theme).. there is a way to make the window edge border wider then 1 pixel... I often use 3 to 5 pixel to make it easy to grab on hi-resolutions displays and hi DPI monitors.

There doesn't seem to be an easy or obvious way to do this with the Gnome X-Windowing system?

Does any one know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a google site search:

Google: "theme create site:library.gnome.org/users/"

I found the info I was looking for on the official Gnome site in the Administrator documentation section:

The Intro Gnome docs URL that talks about creating your own or modifying existing theme settings:
http://library.gnome.org/admin/syste...mes-15.html.en

And the detailed settings file docs can be found in here some where.
http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/index.html

The default installed Gnome themes are found here on a Gnome install:
/usr/share/themes/theme-name

```
[13:07:40 hholtmann@v-00000018:/usr/share/themes]
$ ls
AgingGorilla/  ClearlooksClassic/  Dust/       HighContrastInverse/            HumanLogin/  Mist/                 Redmond/
Atlanta/       Crux/               Dust Sand/  HighContrastLargePrintInverse/  Industrial/  New Wave/             Simple/
Bright/        DarkRoom/           Emacs/      Human/                          Inverted/    New Wave Dark Menus/  ThinIce/
Clearlooks/    Default/            Esco/       Human-Clearlooks/               Metabox/     Raleigh/
```

and inside each theme folder there is the following structure:

```
[13:07:41 hholtmann@v-00000018:/usr/share/themes]
$ tree Clearlooks
Clearlooks
|-- gtk-2.0
|   `-- gtkrc
|-- index.theme
`-- metacity-1
    `-- metacity-theme-1.xml
```

All the details theme settings such as border and edge widths are in the "gtkrc" file:

Every Gnome theme object can reference pre-defined style blocks with attributes.

Most styles have an xthickness and ythickness value defaulting to = 1

```
style "default" {
    xthickness = 1
    ythickness = 1
.
.
}
```

Changing the x/ythickness values can change the pixel thickeness of all objects.

This blog post also provides an example of creating a new theme and changing it.

> http://martin.ankerl.com/2008/10/10/how-to-make-a-compact-gnome-theme/

Answer (score 3):

First find your current theme:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
```

Then edit the xml properties file `/usr/share/themes/"ThemeNameFromPrevStep"/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml`. Change width properties from 1 to 3 or 5 etc.

Answer (score 1):

For the Ambiance theme on Ubuntu 11.04, the diff below fattens up the borders.

I assume you can apply a similar diff to other themes.

```
--- /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml.1    2011-07-01 22:09:31.595731506 +1000
+++ /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml  2011-07-02 12:02:35.077593280 +1000
@@ -11,9 +11,9 @@

 <!-- General window layout -->
 <frame_geometry name="frame_geometry_normal" title_scale="medium" rounded_top_left="true" rounded_top_right="true"  rounded_bottom_left="false" rounded_bottom_right="false">
-   <distance name="left_width" value="1"/>
+   <distance name="left_width" value="3"/>
-   <distance name="right_width" value="1"/>
+   <distance name="right_width" value="3"/>
-   <distance name="bottom_height" value="1"/>
+   <distance name="bottom_height" value="3"/>
    <distance name="left_titlebar_edge" value="10"/>
    <distance name="right_titlebar_edge" value="10"/>
    <distance name="button_width" value="18"/>
@@ -198,16 +198,12 @@
 <!-- Window Frames -->

 <draw_ops name="draw_frame">
-    <rectangle color="shade/#3c3b37/0.7" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height" filled="true"/>
-    <gradient type="vertical" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="60">
-        <color value="shade/#3c3b37/1.2" />
-        <color value="shade/#3c3b37/0.7" />
-    </gradient>
+    <rectangle color="#3c3b37" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height" filled="true"/>
 </draw_ops>

 <!-- bottom border -->
 <draw_ops name="bottom_edge">
-   <line color="shade/#3c3b37/0.7" x1="0" x2="width" y1="height-1" y2="height-1"/>
+    <rectangle color="#3c3b37" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height" filled="true"/>
 </draw_ops>

 <draw_ops name="border">
```

Answer (score 0):

The Dust theme [has very large left and right borders](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dusttheme/+bug/563218):

[image: dust theme]

It is probably already installed; try selecting it in appearance settings.

Comment: But how do I change the window-edge pixel-width on any theme? I guess I need to find and read the docs on theme settings files.. if I can find the docs???